# failing to run an ionic app built with react on adroid studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework

I've built in VScode an app using ionic & react frameworks. the app works and now i want to build it in android studio.

I've tried running the following commands to copy the app from vscode to android studio:
ionic capacitor add android
ionic build
npx cap copy
npx cap open android

My problem is that when I execute the last command, the android studio interface opens but gradle fails at building my program and returns about 170+ exceptions:
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:135)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptTarget.addConfiguration(DefaultScriptTarget.java:74)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:138)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
... 171 more

I've tried about everything to solve the issue:
followed all the steps in the official tutorial using capacitor.
set up new env variables for JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME.
re-installed ionice.
deleted the .gradle folder in my dir.

but nothing works.

am i doing something wrong? if not, then what might be the issue here?

thanks,

I've tried about everything to solve the issue:
set up new env variables for JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME
re-installed ionice
deleted the .gradle folder in my dir
but nothing works.